# dynamically set style to jquery tooltip

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, styles

I am using **jquery tooltip** for label within a grid,for setting color to the tooltip is used this style

```
<style type="text/css">
            .ui-tooltip
            {
                background: lightblue;
            }
 </style>
```

i have used two color for my form theme,light red and light blue,as my style for tooltip is static i am not able to change the tooltip color to red when user selects red theme red

code for changing the form theme

```
 protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strMsg = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (Session["AppTheme"] != null)
            {
                string _theme = Session["AppTheme"].ToString();
                if (_theme != null)
                {
                    Page.Theme = _theme;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Session["AppTheme"] = "DarkBlue";
                Page.Theme = Session["AppTheme"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           strMsg = "Error Details : " + ex.Message;

        }
    }
```

where to manage the code for changing the color of tooltip,
Any help will be appretiated.

Comment: Have a look at [Tooltip Custom styling](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style)

Comment: i saw that but my problem cannot be solved by that @axrwkr